# What will be the value of j after this C code is executed?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Why is the value of `j` zero after below code is executed?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    if (i && (j = i + 10))
    //do something ;
}
```

Why is the value `10` if I replace the logical and with bitwise and?

Also, why is the value of j again zero after execution of below code?

```
    int i = 10, j = 0;

    if (i || (j = i + 10))

        //do something

        ;
```

Comment: Because logical operations are short-circuited. Bitwise ones are not.

Comment: What else do you expect? Why?

Comment: In the last case, in case of || operator as i is not 1, it should not short-circuit and proceed further. Then j should become 10. That's what I expect @Olaf

Comment: @RajeshSh In C, *All* non-zero integers are true, not just `1`. Zero is false. So, `true || something` evaluates to `true` and `something` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

Because logical and (`&&`) short-circuits. Consider:

```
a() && b() && c();
```

if `a()` returns false, by definition of the *and* operation, the whole result will be false, so there's no need to compute `b()` and `c()` (and in fact, C will not execute `b()` and `c()`). In your case, `&&` gives up after noticing that `i == 0` (which is false in C).

Similarly, logical or (`||`) short-circuits on first expression that evaluates to true. Consider:

```
a() || b() || c()
```

if `a()` still returns false (as per previous example), but `b()` returns true, then `c()` will not be evaluated as the value of the whole logical operation is already known after evaluating `b()`.

Bitwise and (`&`) is something entirely different from logical and. You use logical and for control flow (deciding what code to run); you use bitwise and to calculate *and* operation on bits. Bitwise operations are not like logical operations, they're more like *arithmetical* operations - they behave similarly to e.g. `+` or `*`.

Comment: It not only unnecessary to do `b()`, but in many cases strictly forbidden. Consider the something like `if (x != NULL &&  strlen(x)>2)` - the right part would probably crash when evaluated.

Comment: I meant unnecessary from the perspective of knowing the value of the operation. C is indeed specified to always short-circuit where it can on logical operations, exactly so that it can support code like in your example.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller - `but in many cases strictly forbidden`... Well, more than that. It is **always** strictly forbidden.

Comment: @4386427 You are of course right. I wanted to point out the fatal consequences that would happen in many cases, but the specification is unambiguous

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to think on the `&&` short-circuit as the following:

```
int main()
{
   int i = 0, j = 0;

   if (i){
      if(j = i + 10)){
          //do something ;
      }
   }
}
```

This is the equivalent to your example. If you replace the order `(j = i + 10) && i` as you mentioned the equivalence will be as the following:

```
int main()
{
   int i = 0, j = 0;

   if (j = i + 10){
      if(i)){
          //do something ;
      }
   }
}
```

You can see for yourself why the value of `j` will be zero in the first block of code and ten in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Because `i && (j = i + 10)` represents a logical AND operation that **short-circuiting behavior**. That `(j=i + 10)` is not evaluated because `i` is logical 0 (false). Each expression must evaluate to a scalar logical result.

Answer (score 1):

`j = i + 10` is different from `j == i + 10`. The former assigns a value to `j` (in this case `10` since `i` is `0`) and the latter compares `j` with `i + 10`.

When you have `&&` the `j = i + 10` is ignored because it already knows that `i` is 0 so the first part is false. When you make it a `&` it looks at both sides of the `&` operator and assigns a value to `j`. Which may or may not be what you're trying to do - it's not clear what you are trying to do with the code.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to look at it like this:

```
if (A && B)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

is the same as

```
if (A)
{
    if (B)  // So B is only evaluated when A results in TRUE
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And

```
if (A || B)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

is the same as

```
if (A)
{
     DoSomething();
}
else if (B)  // So B is only evaluated when A results in FALSE
{
    DoSomething();
}
```